# Calculation of Percentage Contribution in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am totally new to Spotfire. I want to calculate the percentage contribution of each plant for respective Base Product. You can see in the following picture. I am using follwoing experession to calculate but it is giving me a constant value 1.

**Expression** :

`Sum([Value]) / Sum([Value]) OVER (Intersect(Parent([Base Product]),AllPrevious([Plant])))`

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong.Thanks in advance !!

[image]
`

Comment: I think in your expression the term [Value] is being replaced in both places with the same value from the calculation after the OVER keyword. Try changing your column called Value to something else.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment (didn't have time for a full answer):

[Value] is used in the OVER expression to mark where you want the result of the expression to be used so in the above if the result of the expression was 15 you'd end up with 15/15 which = 1.

To fix it I believe it should be enough to change your Value column to anything **but** Value, I'll use Contribution for my example which is exactly the same as yours but with the renamed column:

```
Sum([Value]) / Sum([Contribution]) OVER (Intersect(Parent([Base Product]),AllPrevious([Plant])))
```

Assuming your over expression is correct this should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its not working. May be my formula is not correct. Can you write the expression to calculate the percentage contribution of each plant for respective Base Products? Please give your feedback. Thanks

Comment: I'll have a look, can you update your question to include your raw data table as well. Doesn't have to be the whole table, just the values that are of interest here (i.e. the values of interest with no aggregation methods like SUM and so on)

Comment: Man..I needed this answer ;)  I cannot find an answer to how to build % Subtotals in Spotfire anywhere.

Comment: Great to hear, I'm in the process of going through some of the Spotfire questions on SO and answering / improving answers so will aim to improve this one with a concrete example soon. In the meantime feel free to upvote if it helped.